# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest transfom into function and callback

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hello I am new in Chrome extension development.

So I have this code snippet

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
        return {cancel: true};
    },
    {urls: ["https://www.google.com/*", "http://www.dictionary.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]);
```

How do I transform it into a function(which i will call blockurl) that I can just call? 
So far I have this

```
function blockurl(details) {
            return {cancel: true}
        {urls: ["https://www.google.com/*", "http://www.dictionary.com/*"]},
        ["blocking"]};
chrome.onBeforeRequest.addListener(blockurl);
```

But it seems it doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#subscription), `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` accepts up to 3 arguments. You cannot condense the 3 arguments into just one function. You could, for instance, use [Javascript spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this:

```
var blockurl = [
    function(details) { return {cancel:true} },
    {urls: ["https://www.google.com/*", "http://www.dictionary.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]
];

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(...blockurl);
```

But that just spreads the 3 array elements of `blockurl` into the arguments of the addListener function.